Strapi API returning HTML formatted response
I am having an error when building my nextjs app (deplyed in vercel) using strapi as cms as follow:
- info Generating static pages (20/42)
SyntaxError: Unexpected token '<', "      <!DOCTYPE "... is not valid JSON
    at JSON.parse (<anonymous>)
    at parseJSONFromBytes (node:internal/deps/undici/undici:5584:19)

I have made some research and it seems this happen when strapi return an html response instead of a json one. The weird thing is this just happen randomly... for example this error was thrown when I redeployed an existing successful deployment... 5 minutes after I tried again and it worked
I have a method that handle all my strapi request:
const request = async <T>(endpoint: string, parameters: Object): Promise<strapiResponse<T>> => {
  const header = {
    Authorization:
      'Bearer ' + process.env.API_TOKEN,
  }
  const req = await fetch(endpoint, { ...parameters, headers: header })
  const data = await req.json() // i am guessing the error is being thrown here
  return data
}

As I mentioned in the code I think the error is being thrown at that stage but as it happen randomly I can not fix it once and for all.
Does anyone has a clue of what it could be?
Thanks in advance

Are you sure the response is your data and not a HTTP Error page? Also, strapi takes some time to spin up when it restarts. If it's behind a reverse proxy such as traefik, the reverse proxy might be sending a 50x or 40x response since the backend service is unavailable or unresponsive.

Generally speaking, when an API gives you an HTML response when you're expecting a JSON one, it would mean that the web server probably isn't actually executing the application and instead is giving you an error page. You'd have to look at the full html response in order to understand what the error is, as those first few characters don't tell you much. Once you know what the error is, you can go from there.

@ChintalagiriShashank you have a point, actually I dont know if it is an error or not! I am not restarting my server but is possible it become unavailable for whatever reason ocean digital has (I am hosting strapi there)... Shane I will try to store all the responses for a while to see the content when it happen
